# Huge inserts in package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, large-files, insertion, package-lock.json

I am new to javascript and just added 2 js code to our appl. One thing I noticed is when I npm install json2csv it inserted more than 10k lines to package-lock.json . My question is that normal? I just dont want to affect other existing codes and new codes my team is adding.

Hope someone can explain if that is normal.

Comment: Looking at [json2csv on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv), it looks like it has 1,167 dependencies. The `package-lock.json` file is used to keep track of every installed package version so that probably explains why it added alot of lines.

Comment: How do you find out how many dependencies a package has with the console?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. I used create-react-app to make my Chrome Extension template, and it had added a lot of bloat like react-scripts. This is normal. It means there is a very large dependency tree, which is something you should avoid like the plague due to security concerns. After removing all the unneeded deps I have 0 known vulnerabilities. I was using an external SSD and one of the packages I installed was overwriting my files, I lost weeks worth of work. Now I have to wipe my entire computer.